# Local Communication Between Services

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm

I have 2 services inside my docker cluster. `frontend` runs on port `8090`, and `backend` runs on port `8000`. How can I make `frontend` call `backend` via local DNS like `fetch('https://backend.local/')`? Because if I use docker-hostname, I need to specify the port to call the back-end. Do I need to have a local DNS Server inside my docker?

Comment: From the `docker`-tag description: "*... Questions about running docker in production may find better responses on ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/). ...*"

Comment: Thanks, I copied my question there

Comment: You might read through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation; it describes what host names will be available in a normal configuration.  However, also note that if your front-end is a browser-based React or Angular application, any HTTP client calls will come from the browser, not a Docker container, and you can't use Docker-native networking here.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, but I use SSR for frontend so it's not a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Software Defined Network (SDN) in docker and then all containers running in that network can communicate with each other using the container names or you can define alias for each and use that. A simple docker-compose file for a backend microservice and mysql database can be created using the below configs.

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  testNetwork:

services:

  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-dev
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - testNetwork

  backend:
    image: backend:1.0
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=root
      - DB_NAME=root
      - DB_HOST=mysql-dev
      - DB_DIALECT=mysql
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    working_dir: /backend
    command: npm start
    networks:
      - testNetwork
```

Comment: The key thing to look for in the above file is the DB_HOST env variable which is used by the backend to connect with database.

Comment: Note that Compose creates a network named `default` for you, and the service names are usable as host names.  You do not need manual `networks:` or `container_name:` configuration.

Comment: if I use this approach, i still need to define the port, what I'm trying to solve is, accessing the host without define the port